# ORMLite throws System.ArgumentException with the message "An entry with the same key already exists."

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm, ormlite-servicestack

I am currently trying to connect to my SQLite dummy db using ORMLite but unfortunately I constantly get the error thrown.

This is the code I use to connect to my DB:

```
var debug_string = @"Data Source=.\SQLiteDatabase\Company_DB.db;Version=3;";

string connectionString = debug_string;
IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqliteDialect.Provider);

try
{
    using (var dbconn = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
    {
    // some code
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var message = ex.Message;
    var innerEx = ex.InnerException;

}
```

As soon as the breakpoint hits the using statement opening the database connection it throws me a `System.ArgumentException` with the message `An entry with the same key already exists.`

Does anyone have an Idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem. Seems like version 6.11 of ORMLite is buggy and doesn't work properly. Downgraded the NuGet package to 6.10 and it works like a charm.